# initial and terminal object make the category unique?

Tags: functional-programming, category-theory

I've been reading Carli Masimo book "Functional programming in Kotlin by tutorials" and there is a sentence not clear for me.

> Not all categories have initial and terminal objects but, if they do, they are
> unique. In logic, the initial object has the name False and the terminal object
> True.

what the unique means? the category or the initial-terminal? IMO, just the pair is unique, but it's likely the obvious by their name's meaning. and i think we can put more elements into sets of category so we can't say that the category unique. But i'm not sure because category theory is a mess with me. Thanks and appreciate any help.

Comment: Despite being rooted in programming, this question may be more appropriate on https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. If a category has a terminal object, the terminal object is unique (up to isomorphism). Similarly, if a category has an initial object, the initial object is unique (again up to isomorphism).